# How to connect PLC to C# 2.0

Tags: c#, plc

How do I connect the Sigma PLC to C#

I have `BaudRate`, `Parity`, `StopBits` and `DataBits`.

and write/send the data from C# to PLC.

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort por = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     por.BaudRate = 9600;
     por.Parity = None;
     por.StopBits = 1;
     por.DataBits = 8;

     por.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(por_DataReceived);
     por.Open();

}
```

Comment: if it is serial, google `System.IO.SerialPort`

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            por.BaudRate = 9600;
            por.Parity = None;
            por.StopBits = 1;
            por.DataBits = 8;
            

            por.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(por_DataReceived);
            por.Open();

        }

Comment: Is it not possible to use OPC DA?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Sigma support ModbusRTU. You can use AdvancedHMI which includes a Modbus driver that makes it very easy to use with VB or C#